# What elements are in $Q_4$ if defined as $\langle a,b \space|\space a^4=e, a^2=b^2, b^{-1}ab=a^3 \rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to write a proof about Hamiltonian Paths and was given two groups.  One is a simple group made up of cycle groups and I can easily figure it out.  I'm trying to figure out the elements in $Q_4$ as defined $\langle a,b \space|\space  a^4=e, a^2=b^2, b^{-1}ab=a^3 \rangle$

I assume it consists of at least the following elements:

$$
e, a^2, a^3, b^{-1}, b, b^2
$$

I think I'm missing 2.  Shouldn't $Q_4$ be order 8?

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by computing some products of the generators then see what the list collapses down to:
We might start with 
$$e, a, a^2, a^3, b, b^2, b^3, ab, ba.$$
Noticing that $a^2=b^2$ reduces the list to 
$$e, a, a^2, a^3, b, b^3, ab, ba.$$

At this point we can check that we have the whole group by ensuring that multiplication of any element in this list on either side by $a$ or $b$ gives an element of this list, and that each element of the list has an inverse in this list. I will check the latter. 
$$a \cdot a^3= e\\ a^2\cdot a^2=e \\
a^3 \cdot a=e\\ b \cdot b^3 = e \\ b^3 \cdot b=e\\ ab \cdot ba = a b^2 a= a a^2 a = a^4= e\\ ba\cdot ab= b a^2 b = b^4=e. 
$$

Comment: And working out the Cayley table will give me the first:  that is, multiplication of any element in this list on either side by a _or_ b gives an element on this list.  Thank you.